# Error 100, Camera server died

Tags: android, camera

I am using the Surface View and Surface Holder for opening the USB camera. Camera opening but after some time, I am getting "Error 100, Camera server died". I search lots of tutorials but error is not resolving. If anyone knows about this error please help me.

I am using below code for opening the camera.

```
     @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    start = (Button)findViewById(R.id.start);
    start.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            start_camera();
        }
    });


    surfaceView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
    surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
    surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    rawCallback = new PictureCallback() {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            Log.d("Log", "onPictureTaken - raw");
        }
    };


}

private void start_camera()
{
    try{
        camera = Camera.open(0);
    }catch(RuntimeException e){
        Log.e(tag, "init_camera: 2=" + e);
        return;
    }
    Camera.Parameters param;
    param = camera.getParameters();
    //modify parameter
    param.setPreviewFrameRate(20);
    param.setPreviewSize(640, 480);
    camera.setParameters(param);
    try {
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
        camera.startPreview();
    } catch (Exception e) {

        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mCamera = Camera.open(mCameraId);
mCamera.setErrorCallback(new Camera.ErrorCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onError(int error, Camera camera) {
        KLog.e("相机服务出错，错误代码：" + error);
        switch (error) {
            case Camera.CAMERA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED:
            case Camera.CAMERA_ERROR_UNKNOWN:
                try {
                    mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
                    mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(null);
                    mCamera.stopPreview();
                    mCamera.release();
                    mCamera = null;
                    start();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
             }
           }
        });
```